# How to install InfluxDB in Windows

Tags: linux, database, windows, installation, influxdb

I am new to InfluxDB. I could not find any details about installing InfluxDB on Windows. Is there any way to install it on a Windows machine or do I need to use a Linux server for development purposes?

Comment: Builds are now up here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/influxdb/ . (Append one of the keys on to that URL.) Search the page for "windows_amd64".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The current 0.9 branch of influxdb is pure go and can be compiled on Windows with the following commands:

```
cd %GOPATH%/src/github.com/influxdb
go get -u -f ./...
go build ./...
```

Of course you will need go (>1.4), git and hg.

If you do not want to compile your own version, you can also find here my own Windows x86 binaries for v0.9.0-rc11:
https://github.com/adriencarbonne/influxdb/releases/download/v0.9.0-rc11/influxdb_v0.9.0-rc11.zip

To run InfluxDB, type: `influxd.exe`.

Or even better, create the following config file, save it as `influxdb.conf` and run `influxd --config influxdb.conf`:

```
reporting-disabled = true

#[logging]
#level = "debug"
#file = "influxdb.log"

[admin]
enabled = true
port = 8083

[api]
port = 8086

[data]
dir = "data"

[broker]
dir = "broker"
```

Comment: cool, it work! I was looking for how to run influxdb on SuSE10SP2 X64. but not success.

Comment: is there no prepackaged click and run download available?

Comment: Yes, you can download pre-built windows (.exe) installations from https://www.influxdata.com/downloads/#influxdb

Comment: I was trying to run comandline-tool influx.exe instead of the engine influx**d**.exe for a while

Comment: I think you meant to run `influxd -config influxdb.conf` (with the 'd')

Comment: @John The pre-built does not include any .exe or .conf files after unzip.

Answer (score 20):

I struggled quite a lot with this issue, so I'll post the full process **step by step**. This will hopefully help other people that lands on this post.

Table of contents:

Edit: WARNING, this doesn't work if Go and projects folder are installed to a custom path (not c:\go). In this case go get breaks with cryptic messages about unrecognized import paths (thanks to user626528 for the info)

1. PREVIOUS DOWNLOADS
2. COMPILATION
3. EXECUTION

---

**1. PREVIOUS DOWNLOADS**

Go for Windows (get the .msi):
https://golang.org/dl/

GIT for Windows:
http://git-scm.com/download/win

---

**2. COMPILATION**

cd to *C:\Go*

Create our *$GOPATH* in *"C:\Go\projects"* (anywhere but *C:\Go\src*, which is the *$GOROOT*).

```
> mkdir projects
```

Set to *$GOPATH* variable to this new directory:

```
> set GOPATH=C:\Go\projects
```

Pull the influxdb code from github into our *$GOPATH*:

```
> go get github.com/influxdata/influxdb
```

cd to *C:\Go\projects\github.com\influxdata\influxdb*

Pull the project dependencies:

```
> go get -u -f ./...
```

Finally, build the code:

```
> go build ./...
```

...this will create 3 executables under *C:\Go\projects\bin*:

```
influx.exe 
influxd.exe
urlgen.exe
```

---

**3. EXECUTION**

To start the service:

```
influxd -config influxdb.conf
```

For that, you first need to create a **influxdb.conf** file with the following text:

```
reporting-disabled = true

#[logging]
#level = "debug"
#file = "influxdb.log"
#write-tracing = false

[admin]
enabled = true
port = 8083

[api]
port = 8086

[data]
dir = "data"

[broker]
dir = "broker"
```

Once the service is started, you can execute Chrome and go to http://localhost:8083, and start playing with InfluxDb.

Default values for username and password are:

```
username: root
password: root
```

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive step-by-step instructions. Only thing I would suggest is conf file format changes from time to time.  Its advised to use `influxd config > influxdb.generated.conf` and edit what is needed.

Comment: This worked! But the logging on Windows seems non-existent. The Linux version writes to journalctl. Is there a place on Windows that logs get placed?

Comment: Warning: this doesn't work if Go and projects folder are installed to a custom path (not c:\go). In this case `go get` breaks with cryptic messages about unrecognized import paths.

Comment: I have a problem pulling the dependencies; I get an error `code in directory C:\Go\projects\src\github.com\uber-go\zap expects import "go.uber.org/zap"` Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @syfantid you probably figured out by now.. influxdb uses gdm. You need to install gdm and run `gdm restore` (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8733)

Comment: ...To start the service:
influxd -config influxdb.conf...
I believe that this will not start InfluxDB as a service. It will simply start the executable...

Comment: _Versions 1.3 and later of InfluxDB and InfluxEnterprise do not support the web admin interface_ (c) [Transitioning from the InfluxDB Web Admin Interface](https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf/v1.7/administration/transition-web-admin-interface/)

Answer (score 8):

Few updates to [Xavier Peña](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116711/how-to-install-influxdb-in-windows/30127377#30127377) solution to build latest influxdb. Notice the difference in github URL and the path.

```
C:\Go\projects>go get github.com/influxdata/influxdb

C:\Go\projects>go get github.com/sparrc/gdm

C:\Go\projects>cd C:\Go\projects\src\github.com\influxdata\influxdb

C:\Go\projects\src\github.com\influxdata\influxdb>go get -u -f ./...

C:\Go\projects\src\github.com\influxdata\influxdb>c:\Go\projects\bin\gdm.exe restore

C:\Go\projects\src\github.com\influxdata\influxdb>go build ./...

C:\Go\projects\src\github.com\influxdata\influxdb>go install ./...

C:\Go\projects\bin>influxd config > influxdb.generated.conf

C:\Go\projects\bin>influxd -config influxdb.generated.conf
```

Comment: When I execute the first command I get: 
`can't load package: package github.com/influxdata/influxdb: no buildable Go source files in C:\Go\src\github.com\influxdata\influxdb`

Comment: after the build process I didn't find the bin folder under project directory. Can you please update the process steps?

Answer (score 3):

Windows if officially supported. Go to https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads and download it from there.

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't an influxdb Windows version at Sep 30 '14, there were are only Linux and OSX versions.

Update: Current 0.9 version at present 04/09/2015 have a win version.

Comment: As stated above, influxdb can be compiled to run in Windows.

Comment: @FaresNoueihed Well, there wasn't any version at the time of my answer,  Sep 30 '14.

Comment: Understood, it won't let me undo the vote, until the answer is edited.

Answer (score 1):

The current 0.9 branch of influxdb is pure go and can be compiled on Windows. The main prerequisites are go 1.4, git (e.g. tortoisegit together with msysgit), hg (e.g. tortoisehg).

Using this setup I've successfully compiled and run influxdb on Win7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

The ["nightlies" build](https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/nightlies/influxdb-nightly_windows_amd64.zip) actually has windows executables now. The release version does not (there is [an open issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8960) for that).

Alternatively, downloading the released version and adding the .exe extension to the file names should work as well. You would have to generate the config file using the command:

```
influxd config >influxdb.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2020 - InfluxDB is NOT recommended on windows

After going through countless of articles, it is generally **[NOT recommended](https://community.influxdata.com/t/influxdb-options-under-windows/8085/4)** to install InfluxDB directly on Windows. There are many issues. In terms of performance and stability. Official InfluxDB too does not support windows and has no plans for it in the future. This is further proven as the latest InfluxDB 2.0 does not include any windows binaries.

> InfluxDB 2.0 does not include windows binaries

so?

### Work Around? => DOCKERS for WINDOWS, Try it, it's easy and free

Dockers are free. If you intend to install docker on Windows Server, it's also free for Windows Server 2016 and above (Microsoft made a special deal with docker to provide them for free)

For those who are still in the VM world:

> Dockers are **NOT** like Virtual Machines. It interacts directly with the host's file system via a windows service

Check the link below for a step by step guide:

https://www.open-plant.com/knowledge-base/how-to-install-influxdb-docker-for-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

We don't officially support Windows at this time. However, you should now be able to build from master. See this issue to track it closely and the comments at the bottom have a link to where you can get a compiled binary:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5359

Answer (score 0):

For create influxdb configuration file we can also use the below command

`influxd config > influxdb.generated.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to compile it yourself, the build is done by influxdata and can be found at URLs like : https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb-1.0.0-beta2_windows_amd64.zip (just change the version number to have another (recent) version)

However, as mentionned by Paul Dix, Windows is not officially supported for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Go to influxdata.com click downloads

https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads/

Select version 1.7 because currently there are no binaries for 2.0.

Download Windows binary