# How to install influxdb on Windows OS and access Admin Console

Tags: windows, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, influxdb, grafana

I am new to `influxdb` and trying to install it on my Windows 7 - 64 OS.

Following are the steps done till now:

1. Downloaded .zip file from the following location:
    https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb-1.1.0_windows_amd64.zip
2. unzipped the folder in the following location: `J:\common\influxdb\influxdb-1.1.0_windows_amd64\influxdb-1.1.0-1`
3. Launched the command prompt with admin privilages and run the following commands:

   ```
   1. cd J:\common\influxdb\influxdb-1.1.0_windows_amd64\influxdb-1.1.0-1
   2. influxd.exe
   ```
4. following is the display messages in the command prompt:

```html
 [run] 2016/11/15 14:52:21 InfluxDB starting, version 1.1.0, branch master, commit 800da5732b91c816b0a097acf8887fa2af1efa1a
[run] 2016/11/15 14:52:21 Go version go1.7.3, GOMAXPROCS set to 4
[run] 2016/11/15 14:52:21 no configuration provided, using default settings
[store] 2016/11/15 14:52:21 Using data dir: C:\Users\USER_HP_2013_03\.influxdb\d
ata
[subscriber] 2016/11/15 14:52:21 opened service
[monitor] 2016/11/15 14:52:21 Starting monitor system
[monitor] 2016/11/15 14:52:21 'build' registered for diagnostics monitoring
[monitor] 2016/11/15 14:52:21 'runtime' registered for diagnostics monitoring
[monitor] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 'network' registered for diagnostics monitoring
[monitor] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 'system' registered for diagnostics monitoring
[shard-precreation] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Starting precreation service with check
interval of 10m0s, advance period of 30m0s
[snapshot] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Starting snapshot service
[continuous_querier] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Starting continuous query service
[httpd] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Starting HTTP service
[httpd] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Authentication enabled: false
[httpd] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Listening on HTTP: [::]:8086
[retention] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Starting retention policy enforcement service wi
th check interval of 30m0s
[run] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Listening for signals
2016/11/15 14:52:22 Sending usage statistics to usage.influxdata.com
[monitor] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Storing statistics in database '_internal' retenti
on policy 'monitor', at interval 10s
[shard] 2016/11/15 14:52:40 C:\Users\USER_HP_2013_03\.influxdb\data\_internal\mo
nitor\1 database index loaded in 0s
```

**Question:**

When I am trying to access `admin console` using http://localhost:8083, getting `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:8083.`

and if I try connecting using http://localhost:8086, getting `404 not found`.

Help me in accessing admin console of influxdb.

Added command prompt screenshot:
[image]

EDIT:
I tried the steps in following links:

1. [How to install InfluxDB in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116711/how-to-install-influxdb-in-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for `..\influxdb-versiona.b.c.d\influxdb.conf`  file to enable Admin

It is in HOCON format Look for `[admin]` section. and uncomment it

```
from # [admin] to admin
```

By default, it will be commented "#" is used to comment in HOCON format.
Uncomment the `binding address` and `enabled = false`

```
Change the enabled from false to true.
```

Run the following command

influxd -config influxdb.conf

Acces the Admin interface by using the `http://localhost:8083/` url.

Answer (score 1):

> [httpd] 2016/11/15 14:52:22 Listening on HTTP: [::]:**8086**

You should be using http://localhost:8086 URL, I have no idea where did you get this `8083` from.

---

You might find [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool easier for use, apart from real-time results analysis it provides powerful [Fass/Fail Criteria subsystem](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/), [Resource Monitoring](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Monitoring/) and much more

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for suggesting the better tool, exploring the same now. 8083 is the port used to access Admin Console from Web UI. From influxdb1.1 onwards, Admin Console is deprecated. and 8086 port is used for HTTP API access as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2020 - InfluxDB is NOT recommended on windows

After going through countless of articles, it is generally **[NOT recommended](https://community.influxdata.com/t/influxdb-options-under-windows/8085/4)** to install InfluxDB directly on Windows. There are many issues. In terms of performance and stability. Official InfluxDB too does not support windows and has no plans for it in the future. This is further proven as the latest InfluxDB 2.0 does not include any windows binaries.

> InfluxDB 2.0 does not include windows binaries

so?

### Work Around? => DOCKERS for WINDOWS, Try it, it's easy and free

Dockers are free. If you intend to install docker on Windows Server, it's also free for Windows Server 2016 and above (Microsoft made a special deal with docker to provide them for free)

For those who are still in the VM world:

> Dockers are **NOT** like Virtual Machines. It interacts directly with the host's file system via a windows service

Check the link below for a step by step guide:

https://www.open-plant.com/knowledge-base/how-to-install-influxdb-docker-for-windows-10/