# Live User monitoring by jmeter

Tags: jmeter, actionlistener, backend, end-user

I am looking to monitor live user responses through jmeter. Can the backend listener in jmeter used to record live users(end users)? I am not talking about virtual users that we set up in jmeter. But the real end users.How can this be achieved?
Editing to add more details:

Our requirement is to monitor the real users, in 2-3 geographical locations, all through out the business hours..say from 8 to 5.

For this purpose, do you think, I need to have a dedicated machine with jmeter, grafana and influxdb for monitoring alone? I have other testing going on using jmeter and I don't want to use the same machine to do both monitoring and testing. DO you think this is achievable by jmeter? ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following tools in combination to achieve live monitoring:

1. [JMeter backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) - to send results to influxDB
2. [influxdb](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/introduction/installation/) - store the results sent by backend listener
3. [grafana](http://grafana.org/docs/) - run continuous queries for metrics and plot graphs like average response times etc.

Follow the steps mentioned here:

1. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html - First Option
2. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jmeter-live-performance-monitoring-dashboard-grafana-influxdb-sarker
3. http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/
4. http://techblogsearch.com/a/live-performance-result-monitoring-with-jmeter-grafana-influxdb.html

Comment: In that case, the graphite host and port that I need to give in the backend listener should be that of the remote server where the real users log in?

Comment: refer the steps here to setup till influxDB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606715/how-to-install-influxdb-on-windows-os-and-access-admin-console

Comment: refer [[graphite]] section in influxdb.conf to configure the port "bind-address = :2003". whatever port is configured here, you should specify the same in backend listener.

Comment: Our requirement is to monitor the real users, in 2-3 geographical locations, all through out the business hours..say from 8am to 5pm.

For this purpose, do you think, I need to have a dedicated machine with jmeter, grafana and influxdb for monitoring alone? I have other testing going on using jmeter and I don't want to use the same machine to do both monitoring and testing. DO you think this is achievable by jmeter? Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Application Monitoring Tools (APM) like AppDynamics, DynaTrace. Using JMeter you can achieve but you should put a lot of efforts. Using Backend Listener only specific metrics can be captured related to Thread/Virtual Users metrics and Response times metrics (refer JMeter Live Results web page). If the metrics you want to capture are not present, then you may need to write your own Listener.

Comment: Thanks Naveen.It helps.

Answer (score 0):

We use to perform general production app (here- Scada-LTS) monitoring by javamelody. But this will give You general statistics. For per user monitoring it seems You should use  log4j + ELK or other simpler syslog analyzing tool.
Jmeter should be used rather for test environment for stress tests.