# Confusion with transaction per second calculation

Tags: jmeter

I am very confused with the calculation of `transaction per second` .
Suppose that my jmeter log file look like this :

```
timeStamp;elapsed;label;responseCode;threadName;success;bytes;grpThreads;allThreads;Latency;SampleCount;ErrorCount;Hostname;IdleTime
10:24:10;302;10.107.25.219;200;Groupe d'unités 1-1;true;266;1;1;302;1;0;MYPC;0
10:24:11;182;10.107.25.219;200;Groupe d'unités 1-1;true;266;1;1;181;1;0;MYPC;0
10:24:12;153;10.107.25.219;200;Groupe d'unités 1-1;true;266;1;1;153;1;0;MYPC;0
10:24:13;198;10.107.25.219;200;Groupe d'unités 1-1;true;266;1;1;198;1;0;MYPC;0
```

How can I calculate transaction per second?

Is it a constant??

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMeter plugin [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener.

1. Download the plugin jar, keep in `/lib/ext` folder of JMeter and RESTART. Or use [JMeter Plugin Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) to download jar from the tool itself.
2. Add the `jp@gc Transactions Per Second` graph from the `Listener` menu, to your Test Plan.
3. Load the results file using `Browse` button.
4. You can filter only transactions by disabling all the checkboxes related to HTTP samplers and enabling Transaction Controller checkboxes from `Rows` tab.

---

**If you want to build custom reporter:**

**First Solution:**

you can depend on `datatype` column in the result to differentiate a `sampler` and a `transaction controller` in the results file.

Following is the sample results file with one sampler and one transaction controller:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime
1480588968698,3,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,434,1,1,2,0
1480588968697,3,Transaction Controller,200,"Number of samples in transaction : 1, number of failing samples : 0",Thread Group 1-1,,true,,434,1,1,2,2
1480588968702,0,Debug Sampler,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,421,1,1,0,0
```

you can check that datatype column is `empty` for the `transaction controller` where as for the `sampler`, it is `text`.

If you are writing your own custom report generator, you can use `datatype` column, in your decision making.

**Second Solution:**

by following naming standards, you can achieve the same thing in more professional way.

1. Name all your samplers starting with "Sampler_"
2. Name all your samplers starting with "Transaction_"

that's it. In your code, you have the control to decide which `label` value indicates what i.e., either `sampler/transaction controller`.

Comment: Thank for your reply , but I wouldn't like to use  JMeter Plugin Manager to determine transaction per second. The result of my jmeter's test is stored into influxdb and I would like to know how can I query or what formula must I use to have transaction per second

Comment: Well, I don't have any solution that solves your issue. You can try out grafan server, which takes influxdb as data source and plat graphs. You can plot graphs fro limited parameters as of now which are mentioned in the link here http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html. So add your influxdb as datasource in grafana server and select the parameter to plot the graph...

Comment: If you don't want to use graphs, then you can access the ibfluxdb data from browser by accessing it from 8083/8086 port (not sure).,there you can run select query and keep where condition as datatype="" and group request by every second.

Comment: This Q & A might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606715/how-to-install-influxdb-on-windows-os-and-access-admin-console