# InfluxDB installation issue on Windows

Tags: go, influxdb

In reference to 
[How to install InfluxDB in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116711/how-to-install-influxdb-in-windows)

I've followed all the steps upto:

```
go get -u -f ./...
```

But am facing an issue as below

```
# github.com/influxdata/influxdb/services/precreator
services\precreator\service.go:32: undefined: zap.NullEncoder
services\precreator\service.go:32: cannot use zap.New(zap.NullEncoder()) (type *zap.Logger) as type zap.Logger in field value
services\precreator\service.go:40: cannot use log.With(zap.String("service", "shard-precreation")) (type *zap.Logger) as type zap.Logger in assignment

# github.com/influxdata/influxdb/services/admin
services\admin\service.go:36: undefined: zap.NullEncoder
services\admin\service.go:36: cannot use zap.New(zap.NullEncoder()) (type *zap.Logger) as type zap.Logger in field value
services\admin\service.go:85: cannot use log.With(zap.String("service", "admin")) (type *zap.Logger) as type zap.Logger in assignment
# github.com/influxdata/influxdb/influxql
influxql\query_executor.go:184: undefined: zap.NullEncoder
influxql\query_executor.go:184: cannot use zap.New(zap.NullEncoder()) (type *zap.Logger) as type zap.Logger in field value
influxql\query_executor.go:219: cannot use log.With(zap.String("service", "query")) (type *zap.Logger) as type zap.Logger in assignment
influxql\task_manager.go:45: undefined: zap.NullEncoder
influxql\task_manager.go:45: cannot use zap.New(zap.NullEncoder()) (type *zap.Logger) as type zap.Logger in field value
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
Refer to https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8016

Go version - 1.7.5
Git version - 2.11.1
Hg version - 3.7.1

```
cd c:\go
mkdir projects
set "GOPATH=C:\Go\projects"
cd %gopath%
git config --global http.proxy http://user:enc_pw@IP:port
set https_proxy=https://user:enc_pw@IP:port
go get github.com/sparrc/gdm
go get github.com/influxdata/influxdb
cd src\github.com\influxdata\influxdb
go get -v -u -f ./...
C:\Go\projects\bin\gdm restore
go install ./...
go build ./...
```

This should help to effectively solve all the problems and you may continue with original link

Answer (score 0):

```
go get -u github.com/influxdata/influxdb/...
```

follow the second answer from the link you mentined (by Xavier Peña)

Or download pre-built binary from https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads

Comment: Hello @kostya

Thanks for your reply
Here is what I tried:

>cd c:\go
>mkdir projects
>set "GOPATH=C:\Go\projects"
>cd %gopath%
>git config --global http.proxy http://username:encodedpassword@hostname:port
>set https_proxy=https://username:encodedpassword@host:port
>go get -u github.com/influxdata/influxdb/...

& I still ended up with the same error as above

Am I missing something?

Thanks
P

Comment: Hello again @kostya

Also I downloaded Standalone Windows Binaries (64-bit) from 
https://portal.influxdata.com/downloads

Followed my original link
followed Xavier to execute
and now I am not able to create a database on http://localhost:8083

Thanks
P