# Influx Db in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, influxdb

I read the documentation , though I would like to gain more knowledge and usage of Influx DB how much worth before start using.

Can some one explain  in detail on the below questions.

1.What is the use of Influx Db backed listener  in jmeter.
2.What is the difference Influx Db backed listener Vs   Graphs Generator?
3.What are steps involved installation and configuration of Influx Database on Windows?
4.Along with the Influx Db do we need to install and configure anything else?
5.How can we send the whole dashboard to the team generated from the Influx db.
6.I appreciate If you provide the detailed steps involved from #1 to # 5.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InfluxDB is a time-series db (a light-weight db used to store time dependant data such as a Performance Test).

Using InfluxDB along with Grafana you can monitor certain test metrics live during a JMeter test and can also configure other system metrics to be collected and monitored (cpu/network/memory).

To store data into InfluxDB, you need to configure the Graphite configuration within JMeter (see [Real-Time results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)). Then you can add a Backend listener to throw this into the DB.

For InfluxDB installation on Windows read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116711/how-to-install-influxdb-in-windows).

As for the Dashboard, I guess you need to use [Grafana](https://grafana.com/grafana) to see the expected test live metrics in a graphical format.

Comment: You can also use Chronograf from InfluxData. It's free and also allows you to do some basic administration of InfluxDB.